# adding 48 to string number

Tags: c#

I have a string in C# like this:

```
string only_number;
```

I assigned it a value = `40`

When I check `only_number[0]`, I get `52`
When I check `only_number[1]`, I get `48`

why it is adding 48 to a character at current position? Please suggest

Comment: "I assigned it a value = `40`" - no, you assigned it a value `"40"`. Do you see the difference? Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow didn't the compilation complain about assigning integer to string type? in the lines "**Cannot convert source type int to target type string**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String is basically `char[]`. So what you are seeing is ASCII value of char 4 and 0.

**Proof: Diff between 4 and 0 = Diff between 52 and 48.**

Since it is a string so you didn't assigned it 40. Instead you assigned it `"40"`.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is the ASCII code of '4' and '0'.

Answer (score 3):

It's not adding 48 to the character. What you see is the character code, and the characters for digits start at 48 in Unicode:

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
'4' = 52
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
'7' = 55
'8' = 56
'9' = 57
```

A string is a range of `char` values, and each `char` value is a 16 bit integer basically representing a code point in the Unicode character set.

When you read from `only_number[0]` you get a `char` value that is `'4'`, and the character code for that is 52. So, what you have done is reading a character from the string, and then converted that to an integer before you display it.

So:

```
char c = only_number[0];
Console.WriteLine(c); // displays 4

int n = (int)only_number[0]; // cast to integer
Console.WriteLine(n); // displays 52

int m = only_number[0]; // the cast is not needed, but the value is cast anyway
Console.WriteLine(m); // displays 52
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing this string and it is outputting the ASCII character codes for each of your two characters, '4' and '0' - please see here:

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/null-character-ascii-code-0.html

Answer (score 1):

`string` is the `array` of `chars`, so, that;s why you recieved these results, it basicallly display the `ASCII` of '4' and '0'.

Comment: Voteup answers rather than repeating